# Convert an arbitrary array of integers to super increasing sequence

Tags: knapsack, superincreasing, polynomial

I have an arbitrary array $X = (x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n)$ of disjoint integers. I want to determine whether there exists a prime number, $p$, and a value $y < p$ such that the sequence
$$Y = \left(y_1, y_2, \dots, y_n\right), \quad y_i \equiv x_i y \pmod p$$
forms a superincreasing sequence. Furthermore, how can I find these values $(p, y)$ in polynomial time?

For example, $X = (657, 527, 423, 163, 326, 522, 283, 13)$, then for $p = 709$ and $y = 409$, we can get
$$
Y = (2, 7, 11, 21, 42, 89, 180, 354)
$$
Obviously $Y$ is superincreasing sequence.

Comment: Did you see [A polynomial time algorithm for breaking the basic Merkle-Hellman cryptosystem](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4568386)?

Comment: It's wanted $y_i=x_i\,y\bmod p$. Contrary to $y_i \equiv x_i\,y \pmod p$, that specifies $0\le y_i<p$, thus uniquely defines $Y$ from $X,y,p$. Without this, we coold choose $p=2$, $y=1$, $y_i=2\,i+(x_i\bmod 2)$ and solve the problem.